# Expansion in power series of a fraction

Tags: power-series, fractions

My question is related to a problem in asymptotic analysis. The answer is given, but I cannot verify it.

*Given the fraction*
$$
\frac{-\left(x+y\right)}{a+ib\left(x+y\right)^2},\quad i=\sqrt{-1},\quad a,b,x,y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
*Then it holds that*
$$
\frac{-\left(x+y\right)}{a+ib\left(x+y\right)^2}=\frac{1}{ibx}\sum^\infty_{k=0}\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)^k\sum^\infty_{k=0}\left(\frac{ia}{2x^2b}\right)^k=-\frac{1}{ibx}+\frac{O\left(1\right)}{x^3}.
$$
I tried to crack the problem by first rewriting the fraction as
$$
\frac{i}{b\left(x+y\right)\left[1-\dfrac{ia}{b\left(x+y\right)^2}\right]}=\frac{i}{b\left(x+y\right)}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\dfrac{ia}{b\left(x+y\right)^2}}
$$
For the first term in the product I get (on expanding in $y$)
$$
\frac{i}{b\left(x+y\right)}=-\frac{1}{ibx}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac{y}{x}\right)^k.
$$
This would verify the first series in the answer above (without the minus sign, however). But I am lost with the remaining part. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.  If we take $x=b=1$, $a=y=\frac12$, then the assertion is that $$\frac{-3/2}{1/2+i(3/2)^2} =\frac1i\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac12\right)^k\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{i}4\right)^k$$ and it is easy to verify that this isn't so.

$$\frac{-3/2}{1/2+i(3/2)^2} =\frac1i\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac12\right)^k\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{i}4\right)^k\implies\\
\frac{-3/2}{1/2+9i/4}=-i\frac1{1+1/2}\frac1{1-i/4}\implies
\\
\frac{-6}{2+9i}=\frac{-2i}3\frac4{4-i}\implies\\
6(12-3i)=8i(2+9i)\implies\\
72-18i=-72+16i
$$
I haven't been able to come close to the formula given.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that  $a$, $b$ and $x$, $y$ are assumed real.

Comment: @Trevor3 Please add this information to the question body.

Comment: Thanks again. I think you missed $i$ in the right-hand side of your expression. It should read: $$\frac{-3/2}{1/2+i(3/2)^2} =\frac1i\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac12\right)^k\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{i}{2}\right)^k$$

Comment: @Trevor3 Yes, you're right.  I was rushing out to an appointment, and I just got back.  I think I've finally got it correct now.

Comment: Your example is correct. Please check that there was a mistake in the answer given above (2 was missing in one of the denominators). I have corrected it; yet, it won't change your line of argumentation I suppose. It is strange that the answer given to me is so far off the right one. Have you come up with anything instead?

Comment: @Trevor3 Of course it's still wrong.  If you look at your factorization, you've duplicated the first sum, but your second factor involves $y$ and the second sum doesn't.  How could it be right?